# Nodejs delay in updating variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I don't understand why my variables are updating so late. I keep on searching and they say i should sync/await it, but i don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
Config.js

global.sql = require ('mssql');

global.dbConfig = {
    server: "#",
    user: "#",
    password: "#",
    port: 1433,
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbort: false
    }
};
```

This is the file where functions are stored:

```
test.js


require('./Commands/Config');

global.Bound_Account = function Bound_Account(ID, username) {
    
    ID =  BigInt(ID);
    let conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    let req = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
            var query = `EXEC dbo.usp_Bound ${ID}, ${username}`
            req.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else
                    var Code = (recordset.recordset[0].Code);
                    
                    switch(Code){                   
                    case '-2':
                    bound_response == "Account not found, please try again.";
                    break;

                    case '0':
                    bound_response = ("Verification Code sent successfully.");
                    break;

                    case '1':
                    bound_response = ("Account is already verified.");
                    break;

                    case '2':
                    bound_response = ("Verification Code sent successfully");
                    break;
                    
                    default:
                    bound_response = ("Error occurred, please try again. Error Code: "+response);
                    break;
                    }
                    
            });
        req.close;
        conn.close;
    });
}
```

And this is my Default file, or the index

```
global.bound_response = null;
....####....
bound_account(id,param1);
console.log('bound_response: '+bound_response);
.....####....
```

So there is how it goes:

```
/bound James (So James is the param1, while id is for the ID of user who use the command, so let us say it is 10)
bound_response: null (It should be "Verification Code sent successfully.")
/bound sahdjashdj (I entered random name so the response should be "Account not found, please try again.")
bound_response: Verification Code sent successfully. 
/bound James
bound_response: Account not found, please try again
```

These are excerpt of my code, sorry if i can't put everything. But you may comment below if you need more.

So my problem is it is delay in updating bound_response.

Comment: you mean ```async/await```

Comment: yes, it is async/await

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` so that your code will wait until you get your result from database.

```
//example

async function example1 () {
  const mssql = require('<path>');
  const conn = await mssql.createConnection({ database: test });
  let data = await req.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
     //procressing with data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is piece of code that is run asynchronously (call to the database), therefore you have to wait till its finished to grab some of the values before you continue in processing our application.

I have simplified your issue to these three lines - the `setTimeout` function below will set myVariable to 20 after 10 miliseconds. Its basically the same as your `req.query(` which also after some time (after getting response from db) executes some logic (in your case setting the variable)

```js
let myVariable = null;
setTimeout(() => (myVariable = 20), 10)
console.log('myVariabeIs', myVariable)
```

The easies way to solve this is not using callbacks as you do, but using promises. I can see that the module you are using is supporting it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql unless you are bound to some old version of this module.

The quick example on that page shows you how to get results and work with them

```
const sql = require('mssql')
 
async () => {
    try {
        // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
        await sql.connect('mssql://username:password@localhost/database')
        const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
        console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }
}
```

If you have to use callbacks for some reason, then you can wrap it with promises

```js
async function run() {
  let myVariable = null;

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     myVariable = 20;
     resolve()
    }, 10)
  });

  console.log('myVariabeIs', myVariable)
}

run()
```